# How to redirect docker container with specific port to domain with https with nginx on server?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have docker container running with 8085 port and I have nginx on the server on which I run that container.
How to redirect that container from outside?

Comment: [Setup `nginx` as reverse proxy](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-reverse-proxy/)